# returning UIImage from block

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, asihttprequest

I have the following code:

```
- (UIImage *) getPublisherLogo
{
    //check the cache if the logo already exists
    NSString * imageUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@&image_type=icon", self.baseUrl, self.imageUrl_];


        ASIHTTPRequest * imageRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl]];
        [imageRequest setTimeOutSeconds:30.0];
        [imageRequest setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
        [imageRequest setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
        [imageRequest setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedWhenStaleCachePolicy|ASIFallbackToCacheIfLoadFailsCachePolicy]; 
        [imageRequest setCompletionBlock:^(void){


            UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[imageRequest responseData] ];
            if (img){
                return img;
            }
        }];

        [imageRequest setFailedBlock:^(void){
            NSLog(@"Error in pulling image for publisher %@", [[imageRequest error] userInfo]);
        }];

        [imageRequest startAsynchronous];
    }
}
```

The issue is that the return value/UIImage is returned at a block. How do I avoid this?

Comment: Note that the method should just be "publisherLogo";  it should not have a `get` prefix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're unable to return anything from the completion block because it's returned `void`.

You'll probably need to create a new method like `setLogo:(UIImage *)image` on the object that's expecting the image to be set, and call that method from within the completion block.

Comment: is it the same thing if I have a UIImage as a property in my class and set that when the block returns and finally return this UIImage?

Comment: Yes it is. In fact if the property were named 'logo', then you could call either myObject.logo = img, or [myObject setLogo:img]. They're both the same operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can place your img pointer outside the block and declare it __BLOCK and use it as a closure. But you really need to be asking yourself what do you plan to do with img, bearing in mind the call is made asynchronously. I would imagine you should make another call in the block to another method and pass in the populated image as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For getting an object from the ASIHttpRequest response, I use notifications.

For example, in the calling viewController

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    // Subscribe notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(onGetPhoto:) name:@"getPhotoNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Unsubscribe from notifications
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"getPhotoNotification" object:nil];
}

- (void)onGetPhoto:(NSNotification *)notification {
    ...
}
```

in your completion block

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"getPhotoNotification" object:self userInfo:userInfo];
```

With your photo in userInfo.