# iOS Preload AlertView in viewDidLoad: Any nicer way to code this?

Tags: ios, asynchronous, uialertview

I'm optimizing my code. In my app if you want to add a category an alert view pops up and asks you to enter a new category name. If I created this alert view only after clicking that "add" button, the popup was delayed. So I wanted to "preload" this alert view into a property which can displayed then each time if someone clicks the add button. Of course I want to do this asynchronous, but also be safe if somehow a user clicks too early the add button and the alert view isn't yet created, that the job still gets done with lazy instantiation. So far this is my code...this probably can be shortened alot but I didn't know how to return from asynchronous methods? Can you do this with blocks?

```
- (void) viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setNewCategoryAlertView];
}

- (void)setNewCategoryAlertView
{
    if(!_addNewMainCat){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            UIAlertView *newAlert = [self createNewMainCatAlert];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                _addNewMainCat = newAlert;
            });
        });
    }
}

-(UIAlertView *)addNewMainCat
{
    if(!_addNewMainCat){
        _addNewMainCat = [self createNewMainCatAlert];
    }

    return _addNewMainCat;
}

- (UIAlertView *)createNewMainCatAlert{
    UIAlertView *newAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Add main category", nil) message:NSLocalizedString(@"Add category explanation", nil) delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

    [newAlert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Insert", nil)];
    [newAlert addButtonWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Cancel", nil)];

    newAlert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
    //Make first letter upercase
    [newAlert textFieldAtIndex:0].autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeSentences;

    return newAlert;
}
```

Comment: I've never been worried about a UIAlertView not being created fast enough by a 1GHz dual core 64bit processor. What makes you think this would be slow?

Answer (score 3):

> I'm optimizing my code.

You're *prematurely* optimizing your code - this code does not need to be optimized (UIAlertViews are created fast enough that you don't need to have one lying around).

> Of course I want to do this asynchronous

If you do it asynchronously, then you have to worry about your code being *threadsafe* - For example, imagine the user hits your button twice really fast.  This code gets called twice:

```
- (void)setNewCategoryAlertView
{
    if(!_addNewMainCat){
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
            UIAlertView *newAlert = [self createNewMainCatAlert];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                _addNewMainCat = newAlert;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In *both cases*, the conditional `if(!_addNewMainCat)` will evaluate to `TRUE`, because `_addNewMainCat` hasn't been set yet.  Now imagine you're starting to use the UIAlertView, and then the *second* time you've called it finishes up.  You've now presented *one* UIAlertView, but a *different* UIAlertView is now set to `_addNewMainCat`.  So if your UIAlertViewDelegate looks something like:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (alertView == _addNewMainCat) {
        // do something…
    }
}
```

This check will now fail, because your code isn't threadsafe.

Multithreading is hard.  So, you should only implement multithreading when you have to, like when you're making a network request or processing complex data that will block your UI.  You don't need to here.  Just create your UIAlertView when you need to use it..

Comment: @Daij-Djan Do you think this question is just a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9474018/returning-uiimage-from-block?

Answer (score 0):

two synchronise two threads use a semaphore/condition

- thread1 creates the semaphore/condition
- fires thread2

in parallel:

- thread 1 waits till semaphore/condition is fired
- thread2 signals the semaphore condition
- thread 1 after wait THEN proceeds

but

I'd advice against your idea of accessing UIKit in a background thread. It very often isn't safe. And i'd not pursue this.

**docs allow creation but say "he only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating" -- sounds not too safe ;)**

Comment: Creating the objects in the background is safe.  From the UIView class reference: "The only time this may not be strictly necessary is when creating the view object itself but all other manipulations should occur on the main thread."

Comment: Ok so I'll try to avoid the multithreading part but still lazy instantiate the UIAlertView. But any idea why the first call of [self.addNewMainCat show] takes 1.2 seconds? Thereafter it's only 0.05. I wanted to avoid this initial lag with the multithreading, but even that wasn't successful.

Comment: @MichiZH It's probably slow because you're setting button text, alert style, etc on a background thread and you should only do that on the main thread.

Comment: @AaronBrager you are likely right. never interact with UIKit in bg

Comment: Not really, I mean even if I do it on the main thread (and I only do it on the main thread now due to all the good advice here, thx :-) it takes 1.2 seconds the first time. There's probably no way around this lag the first time on my iPhone 4s..

Comment: please provide a runnable minimal sample. an alert shouldn't incur a 1.3secs delay